# Meteor add additional fields to user account at root level

Tags: meteor, createuser

How can I add additional fields into the user collection.  I understand the options object allows four fields - username, email password and profile. So on Accounts.onCreateUser,
is there a way to add additional fields at root level (not inside the profile field)?

As of now, the solution is adding the fields in profile with Accounts.createUser, copying this field to  root level and then deleting the field in the profile with Accounts.onCreateUser. This is done for 'userType' in my example below

Client.js

```
Template.joinForm.events({
'submit .form-join': function(e, t) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var firstName = t.find('#firstName').value,
    lastName = t.find('#lastName').value,
    email = t.find('#email').value,
    password = t.find('#password').value,
    username = firstName + '.' + lastName,
    profile = {
            name: firstName + ' ' + lastName,
            userType: selectedUserType // this is copied to root level and deleted from profile.
};

    Accounts.createUser({
        //NEWFIELD1: [],
        //NEWFILED2: [],
        email: email,
        username: username,
        password: password,
        profile: profile
    }, function(error) {
        if (error) {
            alert(error);
        } else {
            Router.go('/');
        }
    });
}
});
```

server.js

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
if (options.profile) {
if (options.profile.userType) {
  user.userType = options.profile.userType;
  delete options.profile.userType;
}
user.profile = options.profile;
}
return user;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The only other way to set the fields is to update the user document after the account has been created via a method call. For example:

### client

```js
var extraFields = {
  newField1: 'foo',
  newField2: 'bar'
};

Accounts.createUser(..., function(err1) {
  if (err1) {
    alert(err1);
  } else {
    Meteor.call('setUserFields', extraFields, function(err2) {
      if (err2) {
        alert(err2);
      } else {
        Router.go('/');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

### server

```js
Meteor.methods({
  setUserFields: function(extraFields) {
    // TODO: change this check to match your user schema
    check(extraFields, {
      newField1: Match.Optional(String),
      newField2: Match.Optional(String)
    });

    return Meteor.users.update(this.userId, {$set: extraFields});
  }
});
```

The main problem with this approach is that the user can open up the console and invoke the `setUserFields` method whenever she wants to. That may or may not be a problem depending on your use case. You can always add additional checks to the method to prevent subsequent updates if necessary.

Comment: This is a workable solution. Thanks for pointing out the security issue. For my use case I do not wish the user having control. I may resort to keeping the additional fields in the profile.

Answer (score 1):

I have abled to create additional fields with out any value (null) on the Accounts.onCreateUser.

Please point out any problems with this solution. **Remember to publish the additional field.**

server.js

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
if (options.profile) {
if (options.profile.userType) {
  user.userType = options.profile.userType;
  delete options.profile.userType;
  user.newfieldone = options.newfieldone; //this is the line to insert new field
  user.newfieldtwo = options.newfieldtwo;
}
user.profile = options.profile;
}
return user;
});


Meteor.publish(null, function() {
// automatically publish the userType for the connected user
// no subscription is necessary
return Meteor.users.find(this.userId, {fields: {newfieldone: 1, newfieldtwo: 1}});
});
```